# Use of undefined constant DB_SERVER - assumed 'DB_SERVER'

Tags: php

I have the following php code :

```
$db_host = "localhost";
$db_user = "root";
$db_pass = "";
$db_name = "photos";

define(DB_SERVER,$db_host);
define(DB_USER,$db_user);
define(DB_PASS,$db_pass);
define(DB_NAME,$db_name);
```

I am defining `DB_SERVER` and all the other ones as you can see above, but for some reason I get the following errors :

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant DB_SERVER - assumed 'DB_SERVER' in /Users/ahoura/Sites/photos/include/config.php on line 34 Notice: Use of undefined constant DB_USER - assumed 'DB_USER' in /Users/ahoura/Sites/photos/include/config.php on line 35 Notice: Use of undefined constant DB_PASS - assumed 'DB_PASS' in /Users/ahoura/Sites/photos/include/config.php on line 36 Notice: Use of undefined constant DB_NAME - assumed 'DB_NAME' in /Users/ahoura/Sites/photos/include/config.php on line 37
```

What am I doing wrong!?!?!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to quote the names of your new constants in `define()`

```
define('DB_SERVER',$db_host);
define('DB_USER',$db_user);
define('DB_PASS',$db_pass);
define('DB_NAME',$db_name);
```

The notice indicates that PHP did in fact treat them as quoted strings because it could not locate existing constants with those names, but this is bad practice to rely on.  `define()` takes a string as the name of the constant to be defined, and its intended value.

Comment: thanks alot... its strange because I have been using it the way I pasted the code up there, but this time its showing the errors!!!

Comment: @AhouraGhotbi perhaps `display_errors` had been turned off before. Always develop with `display_errors = on`

Comment: yea I guess :) ... this is an old script I am running again and now I have `display_errors` on all the time...

Answer (score 0):

This does not answer the question but it is just for people who might have this issue, **when declaring variables for global constants please use single quotes and not double quotes.** I made this mistake and it took me a week to figure the issue out once it was uploaded to the server.

Do not do this:

```
define("DB_SERVER",$db_host);
define("DB_USER",$db_user);
define("DB_PASS",$db_pass);
define("DB_NAME",$db_name);
```

Do this:

```
define('DB_SERVER',$db_host);
define('DB_USER',$db_user);
define('DB_PASS',$db_pass);
define('DB_NAME',$db_name);
```

Answer (score -1):

Encountered the same issue, on research these worked for me :
1. Rename your file config.php to something very unique like config123.php, be        ure to change the require statement too. Probably caused by a conflict with the     config.php file inside of PHP PEAR.
2. Require your file with:
        require dirname(**FILE**) . '/config.php';
3. Remove PEAR from the php.ini include_path setting, if you will never need it.

Source :https://community.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?p=204776

Answer (score -2):

I will just use database info in to class directly rather then importing from different files. This could be the problem with XAMPP 1.6.7 the latest version I guess.anyways you can try this out.

```
<?php

    class MySQLDatabase {

        private $connection;

        function __construct() {
           $this->open_connection();
        }

        public function open_connection() {
            $this->connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
            if (!$this->connection) {
                die("Database connection failed: " . mysql_error());
            } else {
                $db_select = mysql_select_db("photo_gallery", $this->connection);
                if (!$db_select) {
                    die("Database selection failed: " . mysql_error());
                }
            }
        }
    }

    $database = new MySQLDatabase();
?>
```

Comment: I fail to see how this adds anything to a question that was already answered. There is also a very good reason to have one class that holds db info: it's one and only file to change when your database info changes.